# Free TimeSlot returning empty array

Tags: mysql

Here's a query to create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appschedule` (
  `PID` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Surgery` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Activity` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AppDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AppSlot` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `TimeFrom` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `TimeTo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `StartTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `EndTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AppTag` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `AppID` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `AppDateNum` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `AppNum` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here's the insert query

```
INSERT INTO `appschedule` 
(`PID`, `Surgery`, `Activity`, `Duration`, `AppDate`, `AppSlot`, `TimeFrom`, 
 `TimeTo`,    `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `AppTag`, `Status`, `AppID`, `AppDateNum`, 
`AppNum`) 
VALUES
('PID-2014-06-02-00001', 'Single', 'Extraction Of Incisors', 10, '2014-07-03
  00:00:00', 
 'Old', '17:30', '17:41', '2014-07-03 17:30:00', '2014-07-03 17:41:00', 
 'Single', '0', 'APP-2014-07-03-00001', '2014-07-03', 1);
```

Now I want to get free timeslots from the above time Schedule

So I put this query

```
SELECT AvailStartTime, AvailEndTime 
    FROM 
        ( SELECT @lastEndTime as AvailStartTime, 
          StartTime as AvailEndTime, 
          @lastEndTime := EndTime 
           FROM (SELECT StartTime, EndTime 
                 FROM appschedule 
                  WHERE AppDateNum = '2014-07-03' 
                  AND AppDateNum = '2014-07-03' 
                  AND EndTime >= '2014-07-03 17:30' 
                  AND StartTime < '2014-07-03 21:30' 
                  ORDER BY StartTime) e JOIN 
                 (SELECT @lastEndTime := NULL) init) x 
                 WHERE AvailEndTime > DATE_ADD(AvailStartTime, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

but I don't know why, it's returning me empty data.

Comment: Well, you use a variable to access previous rows. Since you have only one row in your table, your variable still has value null. Not comparing properly with null value, therefore empty result set. Simple as that.

Comment: But i need to find also the free slots before first appointment and after the last appointment..Can u kindly help me please... I am realy stuck. Can u provide a solution so that i can also get the free slots as well

Comment: Define a free slot. With only one row, it's obviously everything before `2014-07-03 17:30` and everything after `2014-07-03 17:41:00`.